# Does RecyclerView have ANY benefits other than forcing developers to use the ViewHolder pattern?

Tags: android

From reading the docs and working with RecyclerView I am left with the impression that the only "benefit" from it is forcing developers who don't know how to properly implement the view holder pattern, to use it (the view holder pattern).

Well I know how to use it with a ListView and ListView also has a few features (adding headers for instance) that are not supported in RecyclerView.

So correct me if I'm wrong but if a developer knows how to use the ViewHolder pattern effectively, they shouldnt need to use RecyclerView?

Comment: because `RecyclerView` is not `ListView`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In new project you definitely should use `RecyclerView`, it's a newer API. It helps you with animating items and it also has better semantics of updating data in adapters.

Also it decouples the *recycling* logic from *layout* logic by embracing the `LayoutManager` pattern. (And it also comes with few handy `LayoutManager` implementations out of the box)

But I wouldn't necessarily advice you to move your existing code from `ListView` to `RecyclerView` unless you are not benefiting from it - and for basic lists you are probably not.

Comment: so you mean it supports better animations than listview and using it will deliver cleaner, better designed code?

Comment: It comes with basic add/remove item animations out of the box and you can customize them. Since the adapter now keeps track of which particular indices of data are changing, it's easier to update it (and also to animate these changes).
I wouln't say it makes your code automaticaly better, for simple use cases are things quite similar.

Comment: What's goos as well is that it comes with the support library. That means one code for all android versions (and one set of possible bugs to tackle with) and that you can update it over time.